# Encrypt and decrypt a random NSString with AES128 CTR in iOS with a given key

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes, rncryptor

I'm not sure how secure is my solution.

[Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier) has an extraordinary Framework ([RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor)) to encrypt and decrypt in iOS and other systems.

As far as I know, he is using [AES-CBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTR_mode#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29), that in fact is the standard of CommonCryptor.h

However, my requirements, has forced me to use [AES-CTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTR_mode#Counter_.28CTR.29). Both are really similar, so in theory it had to be something easy. But was not.

There is a lack of information around CommonCryptor.h. It is one of the worst explained frameworks ever.

Working with **CBC** you just need to call `CCCrypt()`. However, to work with **CTR** [you should call](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CCCryptor.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CCCryptor): `CCCrytorCreate()`, `CCCryptorUpdate()`, `CCCryptorFinal(`) and `CCCryptorRelease()`

Trying to encrypt my data, I was receiving different data every time, of course decrypting it had incorrect results.

I had 2 big problems in my first approach: the length of the key and the number of bytes written to dataOut.

I sorted the problems with:

1.- A NSString key of 32 characters

```
NSString *key = @"1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV";
```

2.- To cut dataOut with needed length

Finally this is my code to Encrypt and Decrypt:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h>
#import <Security/Security.h>

+ (NSMutableData*) encryptString: (NSString*) stringToEncrypt withKey: (NSString*) keyString
{
//Key to Data
NSData *key = [keyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//String to encrypt to Data
NSData *data = [stringToEncrypt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Init cryptor
CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;

// Alloc Data Out
NSMutableData *cipherData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:data.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

//Empty IV: initialization vector
NSMutableData *iv =  [NSMutableData dataWithLength:kCCBlockSizeAES128];

//Create Cryptor
CCCryptorStatus  create = CCCryptorCreateWithMode(kCCEncrypt,
                                                  kCCModeCTR,
                                                  kCCAlgorithmAES,
                                                  ccPKCS7Padding,
                                                  iv.bytes, // can be NULL, because null is full of zeros
                                                  key.bytes,
                                                  key.length,
                                                  NULL,
                                                  0,
                                                  0,
                                                  kCCModeOptionCTR_BE,
                                                  &cryptor);

if (create == kCCSuccess)
{
    //alloc number of bytes written to data Out
    size_t outLength;

    //Update Cryptor
    CCCryptorStatus  update = CCCryptorUpdate(cryptor,
                                              data.bytes,
                                              data.length,
                                              cipherData.mutableBytes,
                                              cipherData.length,
                                              &outLength);
    if (update == kCCSuccess)
    {
        //Cut Data Out with nedded length
        cipherData.length = outLength;

        //Final Cryptor
        CCCryptorStatus final = CCCryptorFinal(cryptor, //CCCryptorRef cryptorRef,
                                               cipherData.mutableBytes, //void *dataOut,
                                               cipherData.length, // size_t dataOutAvailable,
                                               &outLength); // size_t *dataOutMoved)

        if (final == kCCSuccess)
        {
            //Release Cryptor
            //CCCryptorStatus release =
            CCCryptorRelease(cryptor ); //CCCryptorRef cryptorRef
        }
        return cipherData;

    }



}
else
{
    //error

}

return nil;
}



+ (NSString*) decryptData: (NSData*) data withKey: (NSString*) keyString
{
//Key to Data
NSData *key = [keyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Init cryptor
CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;

//Empty IV: initialization vector
NSMutableData *iv =  [NSMutableData dataWithLength:kCCBlockSizeAES128];

// Create Cryptor
CCCryptorStatus createDecrypt = CCCryptorCreateWithMode(kCCDecrypt, // operation
                                                        kCCModeCTR, // mode CTR
                                                        kCCAlgorithmAES, // Algorithm
                                                        ccPKCS7Padding, // padding
                                                        iv.bytes, // can be NULL, because null is full of zeros
                                                        key.bytes, // key
                                                        key.length, // keylength
                                                        NULL, //const void *tweak
                                                        0, //size_t tweakLength,
                                                        0, //int numRounds,
                                                        kCCModeOptionCTR_BE, //CCModeOptions options,
                                                        &cryptor); //CCCryptorRef *cryptorRef


if (createDecrypt == kCCSuccess)
{
    // Alloc Data Out
    NSMutableData *cipherDataDecrypt = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:data.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    //alloc number of bytes written to data Out
    size_t outLengthDecrypt;

    //Update Cryptor
    CCCryptorStatus updateDecrypt = CCCryptorUpdate(cryptor,
                                                    data.bytes, //const void *dataIn,
                                                    data.length,  //size_t dataInLength,
                                                    cipherDataDecrypt.mutableBytes, //void *dataOut,
                                                    cipherDataDecrypt.length, // size_t dataOutAvailable,
                                                    &outLengthDecrypt); // size_t *dataOutMoved)

    if (updateDecrypt == kCCSuccess)
    {
        //Cut Data Out with nedded length
        cipherDataDecrypt.length = outLengthDecrypt;

        // Data to String
        NSString* cipherFinalDecrypt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cipherDataDecrypt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //Final Cryptor
        CCCryptorStatus final = CCCryptorFinal(cryptor, //CCCryptorRef cryptorRef,
                                               cipherDataDecrypt.mutableBytes, //void *dataOut,
                                               cipherDataDecrypt.length, // size_t dataOutAvailable,
                                               &outLengthDecrypt); // size_t *dataOutMoved)

        if (final == kCCSuccess)
        {
            //Release Cryptor
            //CCCryptorStatus release =
            CCCryptorRelease(cryptor); //CCCryptorRef cryptorRef
        }

        return cipherFinalDecrypt;
    }
}
    else
{
    //error

}

return nil;
}
```

To call it:

```
NSString *key = @"1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV";
NSString *stringToEncrypt = @"Gabriel.Massana";

NSData* encrypted = [GM_AES128_CTR encryptString:stringToEncrypt withKey:key];

NSString *decrypted = [GM_AES128_CTR decryptData:encrypted withKey:key];
```

I'm posting my solution because there are not to much questions for AES CTR in Stackoverflow. Likewise, if someone want to check it and tell me if something is wrong will be very appreciated.

[My example in GitHub](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/AES128-CTR)

How secure is this solution? It is easy to crack the system? What are my possibilities to add more security to AES-CTR?

Comment: A couple of comments. Generally CTR mode is used to supply a sequence of bytes (bits really) to xor with the data to encrypt the data, the same key is used by the receiver to recover the data. This is generally used for streaming situations. In other applications such as encrypting data at rest it tends to be insecure due to frequent coding errors (MSFT has made these errors more than once).

Comment: For info on CTR mode see *Applied Cryptography 2nd edition* by Bruce Schneier pp 205, 206 & 209.

Comment: @Zaph Thanks for your info. I'm using CTR because is my only option. I'm connecting to a chip, through BLE, that can only decrypt with CTR, so CTR. :)

Comment: A major point is that the key can only be used once if there is no iv. But it is probably better to use a nounce for the iv. The most common mistake is to reuse a nounce. The **same key material must never be reused**. See [CSE Answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2993/4747). Basically if the same key material is re-used and the attacker has the encrypted and decrypted text of one message then another can be decrypted with just that information: decryptedText2 = ecryptedText1 ⊕ ecryptedText2 ⊕ decryptedText1.

Comment: Also note that the ciphertext is completely malleable as desiredResult = decrypt(originalCipherText ⊕ originalPlainText ⊕ desiredResult).

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana: I think your post is very useful and I would like to upvote it, but as it stands it does not fit the Q&A format of stackoverflow. Can you restructure part of it as an answer?

Comment: @Zaph It's nonce, as in "number used once", not nounce.

Comment: Oops, typo, to late to fix. Oh wait, can I blame auto-correct? Nope, auto-correct suggests "bounce". My bad.

Comment: The problem of nonce is the meaning in the UK ;) http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nonce

Comment: @Perseids I added a question about security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm listing this as a separate answer, but I'm just amplifying what Zaph has already said:

**This is totally broken encryption.**

It's not surprising that this has happened to you. It is a very common problem when you try to build your own scheme. There are just a lot of places you can mess up. But I don't want to understate just how insecure this scheme is. It is really, really broken.

CTR cannot *ever* repeat the same nonce+key, and you reuse the nonce every time. This is very different from CBC. In CBC if you reuse the IV, then you make it somewhat easier on the attacker to break your encryption. In CTR, if you reuse the nonce+key it is pretty easy to decrypt the message once you have a few ciphertexts. Some good discussion can be found in [RFC3686](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3686.html).

> When used correctly, AES-CTR provides a high level of
>      confidentiality.  Unfortunately, AES-CTR is easy to use incorrectly.
>      Being a stream cipher, any reuse of the per-packet value, called the
>      IV, with the same nonce and key is catastrophic.  An IV collision
>      immediately leaks information about the plaintext in both packets.
>      For this reason, it is inappropriate to use this mode of operation
>      with static keys.  Extraordinary measures would be needed to prevent
>      reuse of an IV value with the static key across power cycles.  To be
>      safe, implementations MUST use fresh keys with AES-CTR.  The Internet
>      Key Exchange (IKE) [IKE] protocol can be used to establish fresh
>      keys.  IKE can also provide the nonce value.

Note that [RNCryptor originally used CTR](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/releases/tag/RNCryptor-1.0). I moved back to CBC on the recommendation of Apple after talking with them about how hard easy it is to screw up CTR. If you can avoid CTR, you absolutely should. It is extremely useful for certain problems, but for general file encryption it is seldom appropriate.

That said, I understand you have a problem in the chip. How is your chip going to get its key? It seems strange to use symmetric encryption with a chip this way. In any case, RNCryptor v1 may meet your needs. You'd likely need to use `encryptFromStream:toStream:encryptionKey:HMACKey:error:` since I assume the chip can't handle PBKDF2.

> Trying to encrypt my data, I was receiving different data every time, of course decrypting it had incorrect results.

Any good encryption system will have this property. That's why you need to send your nonce/IV (and if you use passwords, salts) along with the ciphertext.

> NSString *key = @"1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV";

This is not a key. This is a password and dramatically reduces your available keyspace. Keys are typically going to be `NSData` since they need to be chosen over all possible values, not just ASCII.

Comment: So question regarding this answer. I have a situation where I have a gov contract that want photos and videos to be encrypted on the device ontop of the devices encryption. They also want it to perform similar to the camera/photos application where they can view photos an videos with ease. CTR, from a brief overview, seems like it will let me stream in the bytes and decrypt on the fly. CBC seems like a horrible idea for encrypting large files (such as videos) and seems like it requires me to decrypt the whole file on disk prior to letting the user view this. Am I correct?

Comment: Also @Rob Napier, is there a library that you would recommend that would properly allow this functionality. The major issue to me (and I saw a similar situation mentioned in the forums for RNCryptor) is that I need to prevent other people from being able to plug the device into a computer and copy readable files from it. The information must be encrypted to prevent others from reading the data external of the application. Internal, it's fine.

Comment: Yes in theory, no in practice. CTR can be made parallel, but you don't get it for free, and CommonCrypto provides no support for it. CTR is also more difficult to implement correctly. Small mistakes can lead to complete compromise of the ciphertext. I do not recommend CTR unless you are very familiar with building crypto systems.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to have a review with my team about seeing if we can re work the way the app functions. My experience in this area is sorely lacking meaning it's fairly easy for my efforts to be in vein.

Comment: I have considered building an RNCryptor-like format that specializes in random access (for video in particular), but it is not particularly high on my priority list. I would likely pursue it if it were sponsored by some group (though I haven't worked out an estimate for it yet).

Comment: Hopefully we can re work the flow to adjust for a full encryption/decryption. I guess my last question is how well does CBC handle large file encryption/decryption. You're library doesn't seem to handle a file stream like ordeal and seems to require the entire file to be in memory.

Comment: RNCryptor has no problem streaming. The whole file does not have to be in memory. But it doesn't support random access. As you note, you need to start at the beginning in order to decrypt CBC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96585/discussion-between-thecodingart-and-rob-napier).